# How to upload files to Amazon EMR?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

My code is as follows:

```
# test2.py

from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf, SparkFiles
conf = SparkConf()
sc = SparkContext(
    appName="test",
    conf=conf)
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlc = SQLContext(sparkContext=sc)
with open(SparkFiles.get("test_warc.txt")) as f:
  print("opened")
sc.stop()
```

It works when I run it locally with:

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode client --files ../input/test_warc.txt test2.py
```

But after adding step to EMR claster:

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --files s3://brand17-stock-prediction/test_warc.txt s3://brand17-stock-prediction/test2.py
```

I am getting error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> '/mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1618078674774_0001/spark-e7c93ba0-7d30-4e52-8f1b-14dda6ff599c/userFiles-5bb8ea9f-189d-4256-803f-0414209e7862/test_warc.txt'

Path to the file is correct, but it is not uploading from s3 for some reason.

I tried to load from executor:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf, SparkFiles
from operator import add

conf = SparkConf()
sc = SparkContext(
    appName="test",
    conf=conf)
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlc = SQLContext(sparkContext=sc)
def f(_):
    a = 0
    with open(SparkFiles.get("test_warc.txt")) as f:
      a += 1
      print("opened")
    return a#test_module.test()
count = sc.parallelize(range(1, 3), 2).map(f).reduce(add)
print(count) # printing 2

sc.stop()
```

And it works without errors.

Looking like `--files` argument uploading files to executors only. How can I upload to master ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct.

> --files argument is uploading files to executors only.

See this in the spark documentation

> file: - Absolute paths and file:/ URIs are served by the driver’s HTTP
> file server, and **every executor** pulls the file from the driver HTTP
> server.

You can read more about this at [advanced-dependency-management](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#advanced-dependency-management)

Now coming back to your second question

> How can I upload to master?

There is a concept of **bootstrap-action** in EMR. From the official documentation it means the following:

> You can use a bootstrap action to install additional software or
> customize the configuration of cluster instances. Bootstrap actions
> are scripts that run on cluster after Amazon EMR launches the instance
> using the Amazon Linux Amazon Machine Image (AMI). Bootstrap actions
> run before Amazon EMR installs the applications that you specify when
> you create the cluster and before cluster nodes begin processing data.

**How do I use it in my case?**

While spawning the cluster you can specify your script in `BootstrapActions` JSON Something like the following along with other custom configurations:

```
BootstrapActions=[
            {'Name': 'Setup Environment for downloading my script',
             'ScriptBootstrapAction':
                 {
                     'Path': 's3://your-bucket-name/path-to-custom-scripts/download-file.sh'
                 }
             }]
```

The content of the `download-file.sh` should look something like below:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
workingDir=/opt/your-path/
sudo mkdir -p $workingDir
sudo aws s3 cp s3://your-bucket/path-to-your-file/test_warc.txt $workingDir
```

Now in your python script, you can use the file `workingDir/test_warc.txt` to read the file.

There is also an option to execute your bootstrap action on the master node only/task node only or a mix of both. `bootstrap-actions/run-if` is the script that we can use for this case. More reading on this can be done at [emr-bootstrap-runif](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-bootstrap.html#emr-bootstrap-runif)